# how do you prove that the big theta of a series is its leading term?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, performance, theory, big-o

if f(x) = (An) x^n + (An-1) x^(n-1) +...+ (A1)x + (A0)
how can you prove f(x) is big theta(x^n).

I've thought about it and one could do it by proving that f(x) big O(x^n) and x^n big O(f(x)). I've figured out the proof for the former (using triangle inequality) but could not understand how to do the latter.

Alternatively one could prove f(x) is big omega (x^n).

I've gotten stuck on this question and any hints or clues you could give me would greatly help.

Comment: better move this to mathoverflow ...

Comment: What Moron says. I have a Master's degree in mathematics (some time ago, hence the slap-dashedness of my answer here). The rules of MathOverflow, for me, imply "if I know how to answer it, then it's too basic for MathOverflow". Anything that you would cover as a matter of course in normal undergraduate mathematics is off-topic: "the intended audience is professional mathematicians, mathematics graduate students, and advanced undergraduates".

Comment: math.stackexchange.com though claims to be for any level

Answer (score 1):

Consider |An x^n + A(n-1) x^(n-1) + ... |/|x^n| as x -> oo.

The expression gets very close to |An| and if An is not zero, then for sufficiently large x, the expression will be at least |An|/2.

Answer (score 0):

You could prove that it is both big O(x^n) and big Omega(x^n).

Answer (score 0):

To prove f(x) is O(x^n), observe that for x >= 1, each 0 <= x^0, x^2, ... x^n <= x^n.

Hence, f(x) <= (n+1) * max(A_0 ... A_n) * x^n

But (n+1) * max(A_0 ... A_n) is a constant with respect to x, so we have our bound[*]

To prove x^n is O(f(x)) is actually quite difficult, since *it isn't true* unless A_n != 0. But if A_n != 0, required to prove:

```
x^n is O(An x^n + ... + A0 x^0)
```

By some theorems about limits that I can't be bothered to state, that's true iff

```
(1/An) x^n is O(x^n + ... + (A0/An) x^0)
```

which is true iff

```
(1/An) x^n - ... - (A0/An) x^0 is O(x^n) [**]
```

But now the LHS is a polynomial of the form which we just proved is O(x^n) in the first part. QED.

In practice, though, what you actually do is prove some lemmas about the big-O complexity of the sum of two functions with known big-O complexities. Then you just observe that all terms on both sides are O(x^n), and you can ignore the rest.

[*] That's a fudge, actually, since what matters is the comparison of the *absolute value* of the function. But for large enough x, f(x) has the same sign as A_n, so if that's 
negative we just do a similar inequality the other way around.

I don't think you really need any use of the triangle inequality to "escape" the abs, because polynomial functions necessarily are monotonic outside a certain range (that is, they only have finitely many points of inflection), and when considering big-O limits we only care about what happens outside a certain range.

[**] Another fudge, really I should have written the limit constant M on the RHS, and included that when taking terms across to the LHS. OK, so this is only a sketch of a proof.